# Java HashMap constructors

Tags: java

I would like to ask a quick question.  Are these all the constructors for HashTable?

```
HashMap( )
HashMap(Map m)
HashMap(int capacity)
HashMap(int capacity, float fillRatio)
```

If yes, why the statement below does not generate error?

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Comment: using generics and using the first constructor - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Why would it generate an error?

Comment: If you would like to know which constructors available, you can read the javadoc

Comment: FYI, `<Character, Integer>` is not a constructor!

Comment: *"Are these all the constructors for HashTable?"* No, none of them is a constructor for `Hashtable`.

Comment: look ma, an angular bracket with paranthesis. That is what world calls Generics.

Answer (score 2):

> If yes, why the statement below does not generate error?
>
> ```
> HashMap<Character, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
> ```

Because it matches the signature of the first constructor you listed, `HashMap()`. The other two things you see are [*type arguments*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), not constructor arguments. They're received as *type parameters* on the generic `HashMap` class, which uses the first as the type of the key and the second as the type of the value in the key/value pairs it stores.